# Do something if url matches X, ignore strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something on doc ready if the URL matches a certain page, for example "/projects/"

I'm using this code at the moment:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/projets/") > -1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This works, although if my URL has a string such as "/projects/?r=something", the function above also triggers in that situation I need it to only trigger on an exact match, so if there's a string nothing happens.

Comment: use `.endsWith("/projects/")`

Comment: Great thanks! I replaced the ".indexOf" with ".endsWith" as well as changed the -1 value to 0 and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: no need to use 0, just `if (window.location.href.endsWith("/projects/")) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a string ends with a desired string, use String.endsWith(matchString).

E.g.

`if (window.location.href.endsWith("/projets/")) { ... }`

---

.indexOf returns a number (the index of where it found the string), returning -1 if the string is not found.